# C# winform Reduce time cost add value into datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, overflow

I have a datatable which columns are 5206 and rows are over 10000.
and I show up to datagridview by

```
mydatagridview.DataSource = myDataTable;
```

I solved the overflow exception that maximum fillweight can not exceed 65535 by change all columns fillweight 10 by add columnadded event.
But it took too long time because it set every(5206*10000) columns fillweight value.

Is there any other way to reduce time to set every columns fillweight?
Or any other way to set fillweight value before I add datatable to datagridview?

p.s. sorry for my bad English..

Comment: you can try change your approach and use DataGridView in `VirtualMode`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be: don't put it in a DataGrid view.

Who can exploit a 5k+ columns and 10k+ rows anyway?

Depending on your business problem, you can certainly find a smarter way to display that:

- are every columns interesting?
- can't you group columns of interests?
- what about using [paging](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/211551/a-simple-way-for-paging-in-datagridview-in-winform) to manage the 10k rows?